# RxJava multi Observable execute in order

Tags: rx-java2

There are three observers A, B, C

First execute Observer A and send the data obtained by Observer A

Then execute the B observer without sending data

Finally execute the C observer and send the data obtained by the C observer

How to achieve with Rxjava?

```
   Observable A = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<T>>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<List<T>> emitter) throws Throwable {
                T data;
                ...
                emitter.onNext(data);
                emitter.onComplete();
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

   Observable B = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<T>>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<List<T>> emitter) throws Throwable {
               //no need to call onNext
                ...
                
                emitter.onComplete();
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

   Observable C = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<T>>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<List<T>> emitter) throws Throwable {
                T data;
                ...
                emitter.onNext(data);
                emitter.onComplete();
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

A, B, C share the same Observer

Comment: What are the `Observable`s? Where do the `Observer`s send data? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I have added the pseudo code, please help me see

Answer (score 0):

You can just concat the 3 `Observable`s and receive each `List<T>` via the same observer:

```
Observable<List<T>> A = ...
Observable<List<T>> B = ...
Observable<List<T>> C = ...

Observable.concat(A, B, C)
.subscribe(list -> {
    // process each list from A, B, C in order
});
```